# Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have flutter application under development. When running the app , an error occurs Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'.
I tried cleaning the project. but still same error persists

```
/C:/Users/RdpUser/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/date_range_picker-1.0.6/lib/date_range_picker.dart:1152:44: Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'.
    final Widget actions = new ButtonTheme.bar(
                                           ^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

Comment: You may have to upgrade your flutter version and be sure is the last version of the package date_range_picker, can you confirm this?

Answer (score 15):

Click on the error link to go in ***my_alert_dialog.dart*** and change *ButtonTheme.bar* to **ButtonBarTheme** like this :

[image]

change to :

[image]

It's works !

Comment: Thanks for your visual help but answer is already discussed. Please don't try to repeat answer in different form

Comment: I got "Error: Method not found: 'ButtonBarTheme.bar'."

Answer (score 5):

The temporary solution @pepe-calero referred would look like this:

Add the following section in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependency_overrides:
  date_range_picker:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/LempereurBenjamin/date_range_picker
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this,

```
Deprecated. Please use ButtonBarTheme instead which offers more flexibility to configure ButtonBar widgets.

This feature was deprecated after v1.9.1.
```

Because `ButtonTheme.bar` is deprecated.

For reference, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonTheme/ButtonTheme.bar.html

Answer (score 2):

I just updated flutter and I also keep getting this error. I agree with [@PatelFab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13947836/patelfab), ButtonTheme.bar is deprecated. If you are using ButtonTheme.bar "directly" in your code, just change it to [ButtonBarTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonBarTheme-class.html).

Another solution would be to use the [flutter showDateRangePicker function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDateRangePicker.html).

I have the problem of not using ButtonTheme.bar "directly", but another package I depend on uses it: [flutter_form_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder). In case you use [flutter_form_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder), [the issue has already been posted in github](https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/issues/701) and I bet they're working on it.

I'll update when it's solved.