# Flutter error while running command Flutter run

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new and I'm facing this issue

[image]

Comment: try `flutter clean && flutter  upgrade && flutter run `

Comment: not working.....

Comment: did you upgrade the flutter recently

Comment: yes I update it yesterday night

Comment: recently i too faced this issue. finally i downgrded that was inly solution worked https://stackoverflow.com/q/66027441/11298876

Answer (score 0):

Please use this package  [flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker) And let me know.

Comment: Before upgrade flutter All packages were working fine but now it is not