# I cant debug flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

**I cant debug flutter project**

**this is the error**

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/country_pickers-1.3.0/lib/utils/my_alert_dialog.dart:139:36: Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'.
      children.add(new ButtonTheme.bar(
                                   ^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027441/error-method-not-found-buttontheme-bar)

Comment: I do all of this but the proplem didnt solve

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/country_pickers-1.3.0/lib/utils/my_alert_dialog.dart:139:36: Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'.
      children.add(new ButtonTheme.bar(
```

is telling you that `Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'` occurred in the package `country_pickers-1.3.0`.  Searching for just the error message finds [Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027441/error-method-not-found-buttontheme-bar) which tells you that `ButtonTheme.bar` was deprecated, and it obviously is now no longer supported.

Going to the `country_pickers` package page and finding the [Changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/country_pickers/changelog) and searching for `ButtonTheme.bar` we see:

```
[2.0.0] - 03/13/2021 
Null-safety is added
Fix issue #40 (Country Code Not available for "Lao People's Democratic Republic") by @Tan-JamickoJohn
Fix issue #53 and #59 (Deprecated ButtonTheme.bar is removed) by @phamnhuvu-dev
Fix issue #45 (Search doesn't show all results) by @shadyshrif
Thanks @phamnhuvu-dev, @shadyshrif, @Tan-JamickoJohn
```

So the package owner fixed the issue in version `2.0.0`.

So you either have to a) stop using this package, b) upgrade to the new package version, or c) use a version of Flutter that still supports `ButtoneTheme.bar`. The issue with b) is that the new version supports null safety, which will require you to adopt null safety yourself - see this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety). The issue with c) is that you will be tied to an old version of Flutter, which is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

This is very common error and it is easy to fix.

- **Step 1 :** You need to Turn on the Netowrk of your PC,
- **Step 2 :** Then Also Make sure Your code as no Faults,
- **Step 3 (optional):** Plus, if you are using Git, then check in Flutter sometimes automatically adds some updates, so if it is
  unnessecary remove it or make discard changes.

Don't Worry if You Don't have Git.

- **Step 4 :** Cut the VS code and Start it from Scrach.
- **Step 5 :** Also, use `flutter clean` command, then Refresh the `pubspec.yaml`
- **Step 6 :** `flutter upgrade` it.
- **Step 7 :** Enjoy, #noErrors.

Comment: I do all of this but the proplem didnt solve iam using android studio

Comment: Why don't you go to Your Flutter Folderr then bin and copy the path of flutter.bat, and then seach for Environment Variable in your PC and then go to path, which will be on top and then place the path in the environment variable and then save the path. and cut all the running programms or most sufficiently restart the PC. and then run `flutter doctor`

Comment: and do remove for some time, or comment the code of `button.bar` that you are using in your programme